# How to use two CollectionView in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an existing project which has a collectionView, right now i want to add another collectionView in this same viewcontroller. Already tried different solutions but can not seem to have any luck. Here is the existing code for collectionview:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    if homeList.last?.catList.isEmpty ?? false{
        return homeList.count - 1
    }
    return self.homeList.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if section == homeList.count - 1{
        return 2
    }
    return homeList[section].catList.count
}
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == homeList.count - 1{
        let doctorsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "doctorCell", for: indexPath) as! DoctorsCVC
        doctorsCell.docDelegate = self
        doctorsCell.docList = homeList[indexPath.section].catList as? [Doctor] ?? []
        delayOnMain(0.1){
            doctorsCell.docCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        return doctorsCell
    }
    else{
        let productsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCVC
        productsCell.setData(homeList[indexPath.section].catList[indexPath.row])
        productsCell.fivePercentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return productsCell
    }
}
```

And here is my new code for collectionView:

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return arrData.count
 }
 
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
     cell.img.image = arrData[indexPath.row].image
     return cell
 }
```

Can someone help me to merge this code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is a clearer method is to use a second collectionViewController and a custom container view controller.

That way, the differentiation in the delegate methods is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use two  same collectionView delegate methods (eg -`cellForItemAt` ) methods in same view controller. So you have to check the collection view inside every collectionView delegate methods.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.collectionView2 {
        return arrData.count
    } else {
        if section == homeList.count - 1 {
            return 2
        }
        return homeList[section].catList.count
    }
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
    if collectionView == self.collectionView2 {

      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
      cell.img.image = arrData[indexPath.row].image
      return cell

    }else{
          if indexPath.section == homeList.count - 1{
                let doctorsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "doctorCell", for: indexPath) as! DoctorsCVC
                doctorsCell.docDelegate = self
                doctorsCell.docList = homeList[indexPath.section].catList as? [Doctor] ?? []
                delayOnMain(0.1){
                    doctorsCell.docCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
                return doctorsCell
            }
            else{
                let productsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCVC
                productsCell.setData(homeList[indexPath.section].catList[indexPath.row])
                productsCell.fivePercentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                return productsCell
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: how to merge the -cellForItemAt method?

Comment: Add one cellForItemAt method in your view controller and check the collection view like above

Comment: Thread 1: "could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

Comment: Have you considered using two separate view controllers and put them together in a custom container view controller?

Comment: I have added the cellForItemAt method also

Comment: Thank you @ Amila for your help. Although by using Contailer View i solved my problem. Greatful to @D. Mika